# Is it possible to manually subscribe a message driven bean to a JMS queue/topic at runtime?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jms

I have an enterprise application running on JBoss which contains a number of message driven beans. At the moment, each MDB listens for messages from a destination which is defined via annotations on the MDB class.

Is it possible to set the detination that MDBs subcribe to at runtime, rather than configuring this via annotations of a deployment descriptor?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check out http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jms_ch2/index.html?page=2

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can't reconfigure existing MDB to listen another queue, but you can try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308188/configurable-values-to-mdb-annotations) to specify system properties instead of real queue names. System properties can be changed in runtime through JMX